# Why Reciver function of String get intialized in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was playing around with Kotlin Recivers until i get stuck with this block of code

assume this varaible

```
 var greet: String.() -> Unit = {
        println("Hello $this")
    }
```

- **String** is the receiver
- **() -> Unit** is the function type

And we can call it in that form , which is clear enough for me

```
  "my extintion  text".greet()  //--> prints "Hello extintion  text"
```

**But** 
 with this approch i can't get to understand the trick behind intializing the **greet** 
 variable as we havn't set any parameter and how **Kotlin** idintiy my 
 passed value ("my extintion  text") as A string 
 and use greet exintion on it

```
greet("also my extintion  text") //--- prints "Hello also extintion text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda when decompiled, shows this:

```
 public interface Function1<in P1, out R> : Function<R> {
 /** Invokes the function with the specified argument. */
 public operator fun invoke(p1: P1): R
}
```

And this is how the `Main` method looks like:

```
public final class MainKt {
public static final void main() {
  Function1 greet = (Function1)null.INSTANCE;  //Your 'greet' is of Function1 type which has 'invoke' method.
  greet.invoke("my extintion  text"); //Calling the 'invoke' method of Function1.
}
```

The compiler calls the `invoke()` method passing your `"my extintion  text"` string and prints it

There is no trick, the compiler will eventually use the `invoke()` method pass in the parameters just like any regular method.

Comment: so  compiler use invoke() to pass the parameters , 
but greet() is not designed to accept any parameter , as far as i understatnd greet() is designed to use the current value of String Class as it is an extension function so how the compiler inditify that

Comment: It takes the context from the receiver just like regular extension functions. Lambas are just syntactic sugar and nothing more. Write an extension function and decompile it, you will see that the function uses receiver's context labeled as `this` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Tasser answer i can understand how it works now 
but i would illustrate in diffrent manner so it might be more persuasive for some one

starting with the declaring A simple lamba experation

```
var greet: String.() -> Unit
```

when we defined our variable in such manner our variable as @Tasser briefed is now A **Functional type** that implements "**Function1 interface**" when decompiled 
it has only one **operator**  function `public operator fun invoke(p1: P1): R`

and here we came pivotal part `operator fun i(p1: P1): R`
this function invoked immediately caues it mathed with argument type 
and because our experation `{
        println("Hello $this")
}` is decombiled through implementing the "**Function1 interface**" with operator fun invoke(p1: P1): R  , thats is why my implementaion get executed